# Запрет на перенос строки в QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, pyqt, qtextedit

**main.py**:

```
import sys, random, os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMessageBox, QDialog, QLabel, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QImage
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, pyqtSlot
from maket import *


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Парсер hh.ru")


if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MyWin()
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**maket.py**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(633, 621)
        MainWindow.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(633, 621))
        MainWindow.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(633, 621))
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 451, 16))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 30, 611, 231))
        self.textEdit.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.textEdit.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.textEdit.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QtWidgets.QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustIgnored)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ссылки на список резюме на сайте hh.ru (скопируйте из адресной строки браузера)"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

---

**`Текст должен уйти в право, чтобы сработал горизонтальный скролл.`**

Пример: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **wordWrapMode : QTextOption::WrapMode**
>
> Это свойство содержит режим, который QTextEdit будет использовать при переносе текста на слова

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from maket import Ui_MainWindow

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Парсер hh.ru")

        self.ui.textEdit.setWordWrapMode(QtGui.QTextOption.NoWrap)    # <--------

if __name__ =="__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MyWin()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]